# How can I conditionally set the value of an input using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the following angular binding on an input:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="value in model.Values">
  <input type="number"
       data-required
       data-min="-10"
       data-max="10"
       data-ng-model="value.Percentage"
       ng-disabled="model.IsDisabled" />
```

In the case that the `model.IsDisabled` is `true`, I need to disabled the input and set the value of the input to `0`, if it changes to `false` I need to change it back to the original `value.Percentage` value.

This is as far as I have got as I am new to Angular, originally I had it as a directive but seemed overkill, can I achieve this with the standard bindings?

Comment: When you need?? In button click? and whenever the `model.IsDisabled` values change?

Comment: model.IsDisabled is bound to a checkbox, so on the change of the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

What you can possibly do is create another array in your controller like:

```
$scope.newValues = []
model.Values.forEach(function(index, value){
    if($scope.model.IsDisabled)
        $scope.newValues.push(0)
    else
        $scope.newValues.push(value)
})
```

and now use new array for binding in HTML.

If you do not want to create a new array, you can add new property to models like calculatesPercentage and use that for binding.

And you can keep a watch on model.IsDisabled to recalculate the array whenever it changes.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need watch anything just clone your array and save and take values from it when checkbox's value changes...

Here I created a [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0wRg59nB1T01U9tl2Qp) for you...

**CHANGES**

- `track by $index` I add this to ng-repeat otherwise angular will throw dupes error when we set all values to 0.
- I cut your object a little for this example using Values instead Values.Percentage

  $scope.model = {'Values' : [2,5,8,3,7]};